# How to implement multi-user safe Linear Congruential Generator in Redis?

Tags: lua, redis, uniqueidentifier

I use Linear Congruential Generators (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) to generate IDs exposed to users.

```
nextID = (a * LastID + c) % m
```

Now I want to implement LCGs in Redis. Here's the problem: 
Getting the current ID and generating the next ID outside Redis is not multi-user safe. Redis has 2 commands which can be used for simple counters: INCRBY and INCRBYFLOAT, but unfortunately Redis doesn't support modulo operation natively. At the moment the only way I see is using EVAL command and writing some lua script.

**UPDATE1:**

Some lua analog of

`INCRBY LCG_Value ((LCG_Value*a+c)%m)-LCG_Value`

seems to be a neat way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

A server-side Lua script is probably the easiest and more efficient way to do it.

Now it can also be done using Redis primitive operations using a multi/exec block. Here it is in pseudo-code:

```
while not successful:
   WATCH LCG_Value
      $LastID = GET LCG_value
      $NextID = (a*$LastID+c)%m
   MULTI
      SET LCG_value $NextID
   EXEC
```

Of course, it is less efficient than the following Lua script:

```
# Set the initial value
SET LCG_value 1

# Execute Lua script with on LCG_value with a, c, and m parameters
EVAL "local last = tonumber(redis.call( 'GET', KEYS[1]));
      local ret = (last*ARGV[1] + ARGV[2])%ARGV[3];
      redis.call('SET',KEYS[1], ret);
      return ret;
" 1 LCG_value 1103515245 12345 2147483648
```

Note: the whole script execution is atomic. See the [EVAL](http://redis.io/commands/eval) documentation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Something to start with. But when there are lots of clients trying to generate an ID simultaneously, there will be lots of unsuccessful attempts and the unluckiest ones will have to wait for a while. Still looking for lua analog of INCRBY LCG_Value ((LCG_Value*a+c)%m)-LCG_Value.

Comment: Thanks. For a LCG with a period of 2^31 it works as expected. Unfortunately, base lua can't handle integers larger than about 2^53 with precision. You have to include some library to deal with large numbers but Redis lua doesn't support the "require" keyword. I'm still looking for a solution for a LCG with a period of 2^48.